# Dynamically change the handler of a click binding in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I got the following binding working like a charm :

```
<button class="flatButton buttonPin" data-bind="click:EnterPinMode">Add pin</button>
```

In my viewmodel I define the Handler like this :

```
self.EnterPinMode = function(data,event)
{
    //Doing several things here
    //....
}
```

Now, let's say I want to change the behavior of that button after the first click on it...how could I do it ? I already managed quite easily to change the button text :

```
self.EnterPinMode = function(data,event)
{
    //Doing several things here
    //....
    var curButton = $(event.target);
    curButton.text("Cancel");
}
```

But what about changing the button behaviour ? If I had set this handler through jQuery, that wouldn't be an issue, but is there a way to "replace" the click binding on that control so that now it will call `ExitPinMode` handler, for example.
I've got some doubts on this being possible given the fact that knockout works only with declarative binding (at least without plugin...), but I thought it was worth asking.

Please note that I will actually need some kind of 3 ways toggle, I just simplify it here to a "normal" toggle for the sake of the example.

Comment: Why not store your state in observable object then based on it, you choose which function to call(like an intermediate level function). you got me?

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed one of the solutions I thought about, but as I stated in my comment to Sebastien here under, would that be acceptable to add an observable to the viewmodel only for this use ? I must admit I'm quite new to this MVVM paradigm so I haven't read a lot yet on best/worst-practices. I was already concerned with declarative binding and content/separation but learned to live with it, and would like to do things the best way possible.

Comment: Maybe consider asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a `hasBeenClicked` flag that's private to the view model is fine, and probably the best solution for this.

If you really want to swap out the handler, that should be easy enough, though, with something like this:

```
function enterPinMode() {
    //Doing several things here
    //....
    var curButton = $(event.target);
    curButton.text("Cancel");

    //set click handler to a step 2 function
    self.pinAction = exitPinMode;
}
function exitPinMode() {
    //....
}

self.pinAction = enterPinMode;
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will validate this one cause it looks the more elegant to me and I think it answers the best my original "swapping handler" question. I actually didn't think about swapping it that way. I will now see  if I go with a private flag, this kind of solution, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of the simplest solution is to add a boolean like hasBeenClicked set to false at the begining and then set it to true.

Example:

```
  self.hasBeenClicked  = false;

  self.EnterPinMode = function(data,event)
  {
   if (!self.hasBeenClicked )
     {
      var curButton = $(event.target);
      curButton.text("Cancel");
      self.hasBeenClicked = true;
     }
   else
     {
       //behaviour an a second click
     }
  }
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought about this, or rather about some kind of "state" indicator as I need a 3-way binding, but I must admit I'm concerned about best-practices. I mean, I'm quite reluctant (maybe too much actually) to add variables to my viewmodel if they're not related to my model. Maybe I should just don't bother with that kind of consideration ?

Comment: First I think it's better to be too much reluctant than too little.
But in this case I really don't see any other way to solve this. To do it in a better way you can maybe split your "EnterPinMode" function in multiples functions and then call the one you need based on your indicator value.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, although I would keep the flag private, unless you need to access it outside the view model.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    var nextState = 'firstState';
    var states = {
       firstState: function () {
           nextState = 'secondState';
           //Do stuff
       },
       secondState: function () {
           nextState = 'thirdState';
           //Do stuff
       },
       thirdState: function () {
           nextState = 'firstState';
           //Do stuff
       }
   }

   self.EnterPinMode = function () {
       states[nextState].call();
   }
}
```

What you should try to remember first about MVVM is that you are designing an object to represent your view. If your view will have different states, There is nothing wrong with having your viewmodel know about these states and knowing what to do in what state. Stick with MVVM. You wont be disappointed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually was thinking that my ViewModel had to reflect more the model than the view, the view being the generated HTML. I will keep your advice in mind in the future though and won't hesitate that much to include "view data" in it